# Laravel 5.1 - Remove "public/" of the URL whith Method bind?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I need some help Please, for I'm beginner with Laravel and MVC.
I want to remove the "public/" of the URL.

The only two "solutions" that I found in Google, are:
Either with .htaccess. But with me (and obviously not with me) it's not working.
Either by putting what is in the "public" folder at the root of the project Laravel. This is not good for security reasons.

There is a real solution to remove the "public/" URL? So that for example this URL:

localhost/Laravel/public/test

Accessible only with this URL:

localhost/Laravel/test

Because if it or has no solution, it is of no use that I continuous to take courses on this Frameworks.

_I had read, that there may be a solution with this in AppServiceProvider:

http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/larav2.png

Or with this in the Router or a container:

```
App::bind('path.public', function() {
return base_path().'/public_html';
```

});

But I am beginner, so I do not find the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check you document root directory?

Comment: I do not know how to do

Comment: instead of trying to find ways around your issue I think you should figure out why your server isn't working with the public folder as the root directory.
Are you developing locally?
Are you using Apache?
What does your server config for the website look like?
Lastly, what .htaccess did you try and use?

Comment: I am with wamp.Later the project will be shared with a hoster mutualized, at OVH.

I tried the .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
But that does not work.

Comment: are you running just this one project in wamp? If so you can just change the server config to use the public folder as the root.
Otherwise you can set up a virtual host (vhost) and have a different local domain for this website alone...
I can show you how to do this if you'd prefer. You'd then be able to visit the project at something like http://laravel.localhost/

Comment: alternatively, if you want to get coding straight away, you can navigate to the project root folder where the `artisan` file is with a terminal and run `php artisan serve`. This will launch a quick local server on localhost:8000 that you can connect to straight away

Comment: OK thank you. I do not know how to make. I want that show  to me.
But, the problem, it is with a mutualized Hosting, I believe that we cannot configure his virtual host. It is reserved that has servers dedicated. (sorry no speak very goog Englesh);

Comment: that should be ok, as long as you have FTP access to the next folder above the public folder on the shared hosting. Then you can just upload the project at that level and either configure the hosting to use your `public` as the website public folder (probably through cpanel), or you could rename the `public` folder in your project to match the name used on the server.
I'll write up an answer instructing you on how to modify wamp to get it working locally first at least

Comment: OK thank you. I had read about the French forums that it is not possible to set the vhost with a mutualized hosting

Comment: yea, the vhost option is only going to be available if you're running your own server. It's more relevant in your local setup....
I'll add it to my answer if you're interested. It's more work, but can be useful if you work on multiple projects and want to use wamp for all of them

Comment: OK thank you. so if I use a mutualized hosting, I can not use Laravel correctly?

Comment: No no, You can still use Laravel on mutualized hosting. I've done it before. You just need to copy all the files to the folder that contains the `public` folder. If you're unable to see how to do it you should contact the mutualised hosting provider and they should help sort it out for you.

Comment: ok thank. _"You just need to copy all the files to the folder that contains the public folder."
_what does it mean ?
I need that moved the files that are in my public folder to the root of my Laravel project?

Comment: so when you connect to your mutualized hosting via FTP you will normally be at the root folder. inside this folder you might have a couple of other folders, like `cgi` and `public_html`. Everything inside the `public_html` folder is what will be accessible by the public.
When it comes time for you to upload your laravel project, you will be uploading it to the root folder on your server, that's what I meant (sorry if I confused you). That way `app`, `bootstrap`, `config`, etc aren't accessible by the public.

Comment: Ok thank.
sorry, I do not quite understand.
I called my webhost, they do not know too much ...

My root folder it is "www" : http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/larav3.png

Y have not "public_html", I have "public" : http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/larav4.png

Comment: ah ok, So you will first delete any old files inside the `www` folder on your server. Then you need to rename the `public` folder in your laravel project to `www` to match your server config. Then you just upload your whole project, everything in the `laravel` folder,  to the root folder on your server.

Comment: Ok thank.
So I have first delete any old files inside the www folder on my server: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sdz-upload/prod/upload/l11.png
Then I just sent in my www: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sdz-upload/prod/upload/l22.png
Sorry, I did not understand the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to configure your local installation of WAMP to use Laravel's `public` folder as the document root. You have two options here:

## Option 1. Use wamp just for this project alone

1. Find your `httpd.conf` file. This is the server config, and should be located in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf`. (it's a good idea to make a backup of this file before editing)
2. Open the config file in notepad, find the line `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"` and change to `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/public"` (assuming you have your laravel project in the www folder)
3. save the `httpd.conf` and restart wamp.

Now when you visit `http://localhost` you should see the Laravel welcome screen.

## Option 2. Set up a virtual host

This option is a bit more complicated, but will allow you to have multiple websites running alongside each other in wamp, each with their own subdomain that you can use to access them in your browser.
 1. open the `httpd.conf` file in notepad and find the line `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"`. Change it to `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/default"`.
 2. add the following snippet below this line:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot 'c:/wamp/www'
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName myproject.localhost
    DocumentRoot 'c:/wamp/www/myproject/public'
</VirtualHost>
```

This will create two new virtual hosts running on your local ip. One will work on the domain `localhost` and serve files from the `www/default` folder, the other will work on the domain `myproject.localhost` and serve files from the `www/myproject/public` folder.

3. locate your `hosts` file at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and open it in notepad. add the following lines:
   `127.0.0.1   localhost`
   `127.0.0.1   myproject.localhost`
   This will add two domain mappings that point traffic to your local ip for wamp to handle.
4. Now navigate to the www folder and create `C:\wamp\www\default` and `C:\wamp\www\myproject`. Move your laravel project into the `\myproject` folder ensuring that the `public` folder is here as well.
5. finally restart wamp and now you should be able to go to http://myproject.localhost and see your laravel website.

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

_In His Laravel project: Rename the "public" folder like this: "www."

_In An accommodation (example OVH): remove all that is at the root, including the "www" (except: .ovhconfig).

_Send His project on accommodation.

I hope it will not cause conflict. After I think we should also rename in his Laravel the "public/" in "www/".

thank You